# Using export and source commands in bashrc file

Tags: bash

I'm running bash in Ubuntu, and I'm trying to run a computational chemistry program called Gaussian 16.  My colleague tells me that he is able to run Gaussian 16 by adding the following lines to his `.bashrc` file:

```
export g16root=/g16root
source $g16root/g16/bsd/g16.profile
```

My colleague says that once he adds those lines to his `.bashrc` file, he can run Gaussian 16 using the command `g16 <input file>`, where `<input file>` is the required input file.

My `.bashrc` file is in my home directory (`~`, in other words `/export/home/myusername/`).  When I add those above two lines to my `.bashrc` file and then attempt`g16 <input file>`, bash tells me it doesn't know what `g16` is ("`g16: command not found`").

**HOWEVER**, if I *execute* (separately) those above two lines in bash (i.e., the above `export` and `source` commands), then bash knows what `g16` is: `g16 <input file>` runs the software, and additionally, `which g16` gives `/g16root/g16/g16`.  So this works, but I have to reenter the `export` and `source` commands *every* time I log in to the (remote) machine.

Please bear with me since I'm a bash novice, but how do I get bash to "execute" the `export` and `source` commands in my `.bashrc` file?

In case it's helpful, the entirety of my `.bashrc` file (other than commented lines) is now the following:

```
test -s ~/.alias && . ~/.alias || true

if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

export g16root=/g16root
source $g16root/g16/bsd/g16.profile
```

(I don't know why the first two blocks of code are there.)

Also, executing `echo $BASH_VERSION` gives `4.1.5(1)-release`, so apparently I am actually using bash.

Comment: Put something like `echo hello` or `touch ~/testfile` in the `.bashrc` file to see if it even gets processed properly (Bash by itself doesn't read `.bashrc` for _login shells_, just the `.profile` files etc. Usually they'd also read `.bashrc`, but...) Also, run `echo $BASH_VERSION` to check that it's actually Bash you're running (and not ksh or zsh, or whatever)

Comment: The shell runs `~/.bashrc` whenever you start an interactive shell. Merely adding the lines to the files won't do much. Starting a new terminal, or logging out and in again, will cause the shell to run the added lines.

Comment: I have started a new terminal and have logged out and in again. When I run `echo $BASH_VERSION`, the terminal gives `4.1.5(1)-release`.

Comment: Just to be sure: it sounds a bit like you modify the local `.bashrc` when you need to modify the one on the remote server. Also: `.profile` *should* also source `.bashrc` (if BASH is detected as shell). And: How do you do the login?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by ilkkachu, `.bashrc` was not being processed for *login shells* -- only `.profile` was.  (This behavior may be specific to Ubuntu; I'm not sure.)

I was able to induce `.bashrc` to be processed for login shells by adding the following lines to `.profile`:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
     # include .bashrc if it exists
     if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
         . "$HOME/.bashrc"
     fi
fi
```

Comment: the info file for bash documents this.  This https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files    describes how bash loads it's rc files

Comment: Is the gaussian16 host a server separate from your desktop ? ie you use ssh for example to access it ?

Comment: Yes, the gaussian16 host is a server separate from my desktop; I use ssh to access it.